# Firebase database timestamp is not serializing, getting error {"Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path 'date',

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i want to retrieve timestamp data of firestore collection, but im getting error - {"Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path 'date',

[date field data screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGQt2.png)

[data screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnmsr.png)

sample data set

```
{"Tyres":"12","sr_no":"","TruckNumber":"TS 12345","image_url":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/truck-41c31.appsp.jpg?alt=media&token=2dc86208-7f71-4e3c-876c-70a80d4822bf","date":{}}
```

code

```
Query truckQuery = fireStoreDb.Collection("users/QRRsqyWUas/orders");
                QuerySnapshot truckQuerySnapshot = await truckQuery.GetSnapshotAsync();
                List<Truck> lstTruck = new List<Truck>();

                foreach (DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot in truckQuerySnapshot.Documents)
                {
                    if (documentSnapshot.Exists)
                    {
                        Dictionary<string, object> city = documentSnapshot.ToDictionary();
                        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(city);
                        Truck newtruck = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Truck>(json);
                        newtruck.TruckNumber = documentSnapshot.Id;
                        newtruck.date = documentSnapshot.CreateTime.Value.ToDateTime();
                        lstTruck.Add(newtruck);
                    }
                }
```

model
public class Truck

```
 {

        [FirestoreProperty]
        [Required]
        public string TruckNumber { get; set; }
        [FirestoreProperty]
        [Required]
        public string Tyres { get; set; }
      
        public DateTime date { get; set; }
        [FirestoreProperty]
        [Required]
        public string image_url { get; set; }
        [FirestoreProperty]
        [Required]
        public string sr_no { get; set; }
    }
```

firestore date field data - `29 June 2020 at 22:23:44 UTC+5:30`

Comment: Your `date` is an empty object in your "sample data set". That cannot be parsed to a DateTime. That said, "29 June 2020 at 22:23:44 UTC+5:30" is not a standard DateTime either and won't parse unless you use a custom parser.

Comment: i modified before serialization , its working fine,
city["date"] = DateTime.Now.ToString();Thanks @oerkelens

Comment: If you have resolved the issue could you please add it as an answer so that others have an easier time finding it?

Answer (score 1):

```
 foreach (DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot in truckQuerySnapshot.Documents)
                {
                    if (documentSnapshot.Exists)
                    {
                        Dictionary<string, object> city = documentSnapshot.ToDictionary();
                        city["date"] = DateTime.Now.ToString();//modified here for resolve
                        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(city);
                        Truck newtruck = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Truck>(json);
                        newtruck.Docid = documentSnapshot.Id;
                        newtruck.date = documentSnapshot.CreateTime.Value.ToDateTime();
                        lstTruck.Add(newtruck);
                    }
                }
```

i have assigned datetime now before the serializeObject(city), and my error gone.

Answer (score 0):

I face the same Error in .netcore 5 with firebase Database

**Solution** :

Change in property : DateTime To DateTimeOffset

ex... "`**public DateTimeOffset date { get; set; }**`"

And in databse insert Date always in utc

ex... `**object.date =  DateTime.UtcNow;**`

I Hope this helps everyone....

Answer (score 0):

I face this problem and I solve it
I don't know if this consider a solution but I will share it here

Also, I use this method to convert returned Dictionary to Observablecollection Model

```
using Google.Cloud.Firestore;
```

- 

```
FirestoreDb fdb;
private ObservableCollection<Items_Model> _result = new ObservableCollection<Items_Model>();
public ObservableCollection<Items_Model> result
{
    get { return _result; }
}
```

- 

```
public Page_Items()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            
            MyListView.ItemsSource = result;
            GetAllItems();
        }
```

Items_Model

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

namespace WPFApp1.Models
{
    public class Items_Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _Name { get; set; }


        public Guid id { get; set; }
        
        public string Name
        {
            get { return _Name; }
            set { _Name = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Name"); }
        }
        
        
    
        public string iid { get; set; }
        public string Barcode { get; set; }
        public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
        public string Section { get; set; }
        public string Notes { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore]
        public DateTime AddDate { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore]
        public DateTime UpdateDate { get; set; }
        public string AddBy { get; set; }
        public string UpdateBy { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore]
        public string Key { get; set; }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my solution

```
public async void GetAllItems()
    {
        try
        {
            CollectionReference customersRef = fdb.Collection("Items");
            FirestoreChangeListener listener = customersRef.Listen(snapshot =>
            {
                foreach (var change in snapshot.Changes)
                {

                    var dic = change.Document.ToDictionary();
                    
                    
                    //Here I Convert to DateTime
                    string AddD = dic["AddDate"].ToString();
                    string stringAddDate = AddD.Split(new string[] { "Timestamp: " }, StringSplitOptions.None).Last();
                    DateTime AddDate = Convert.ToDateTime(stringAddDate);

                    string UpD = dic["UpdateDate"].ToString();
                    string stringUpdateDate = UpD.Split(new string[] { "Timestamp: " }, StringSplitOptions.None).Last();
                    DateTime UpdateDate = Convert.ToDateTime(stringUpdateDate);


                    var obj = new Items_Model();
                    obj.id = Guid.Parse(dic["id"].ToString());
                    obj.iid = (dic["iid"] == null ? "" : dic["iid"].ToString());
                    obj.Name = (dic["Name"] == null ? "" : dic["Name"].ToString()) ;
                    obj.Barcode = (dic["Barcode"] == null ? "" : dic["Barcode"].ToString()) ;
                    obj.ImageUrl = (dic["ImageUrl"] == null ? "" : dic["ImageUrl"].ToString());
                    obj.Section = (dic["Section"] == null ? "" : dic["Section"].ToString()); 
                    obj.Notes = (dic["Notes"] == null ? "" : dic["Notes"].ToString()); 
                    obj.AddDate = AddDate;
                    obj.UpdateDate = UpdateDate;
                    obj.AddBy = (dic["AddBy"] == null ? "" : dic["AddBy"].ToString());
                    obj.UpdateBy = (dic["UpdateBy"] == null ? "" : dic["UpdateBy"].ToString());
                    

                    if (change.ChangeType.ToString() == "Added")
                    {
                        App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate
                        {
                            result.Add(obj);
                        });
                        
                    }
                    else if (change.ChangeType.ToString() == "Modified")
                    {
                        if (result.Where(c => c.id == obj.id).Any())
                        {
                            var item = result.Where(c => c.id == obj.id).FirstOrDefault();
                            //item = obj;

                            App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate
                            {
                                result.Insert(result.IndexOf(item), obj);
                                result.Remove(item);
                            });
                            
                        }
                    }
                    else if (change.ChangeType.ToString() == "Removed")
                    {
                        if (result.Where(c => c.id == obj.id).Any())
                        {
                            var item = result.Where(c => c.id == obj.id).FirstOrDefault();
                            App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate
                            {
                                result.Remove(item);
                            });
                            
                        }
                    }
                }

            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error");
        }
    }
```